# How can I change the layout of window in UWP according to the number of items to be displayed?

Tags: layout, uwp

In my UWP project, I want to split my window according to the number of elements to be displayed. For example, when I have only one element, the display area of this element will occupy the entire window. The window will split into 2 windows which is placed up and down when I have 2 elements. And when I have 4 elements, the window will split into 2*2 windows. Does anyone have any idea can achieve such a purpose?

Comment: Do you mean when you have 4 elements, you want the elements to be placed into 4 areas. And these areas are in the same size?

Comment: Yeah. When I have 1 element, the window is 1*1. When I have 2 elements, the window split into 2*1. And when I have 3 elements, the window is 2*2 but only 3 sub-windows have element. And when I have 4 elements, the window is 2*2. All these elements are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Create a RelativePanel with 4 `Grid` containers as content

```
<RelativePanel>
        <Grid x:Name="TopLeftGrid" Background="Blue" Height="200" Width="200"></Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="BottomLeftGrid" RelativePanel.Below="TopLeftGrid" Background="Green" Height="200" Width="200"></Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="TopRightGrid" RelativePanel.RightOf="TopLeftGrid" Background="Gray" Height="200" Width="200"></Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="BottomRightGrid" RelativePanel.Below="TopRightGrid" RelativePanel.RightOf="BottomLeftGrid" Background="Red" Height="200" Width="200">
        </Grid>
</RelativePanel>
```

The Relative panel makes it easy to create an adaptive layout.

Now Bind the Visibility of the `Grid` to the the number of Elements, using a `ValueConverter` which will return `Visibility.Visible` Or `Visibility.Collapsed` depending on your number of Elements.

The ValueConverter will look something like this:

```
      public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        // value is here the number of element, you can create for each grid a value converter or 
        // specify a parameter (like name of the grid)

        // Casting to integer
        int elements = (int) value;
        // This could be a possible if statement for the BottomLeftGrid which should only be visible 
        // if you are having 3 elements or more
        if (elements >= 3)
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            // Not more than 2 elements => BottomLeftGrid not visible
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

You can also Bind the `Width` and `Height` of the `Grids` to the number of elements by also using a value converter.

Further notes:

- You will need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to let the ui know to update`when the element count is changing
- Working with the MVVM Pattern [CodeProject MVVM Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/278901/MVVM-Pattern-Made-Simple)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, your method may be work, I will try it later. Because the elements I want to display are all the same,  both are some kind of UserControl defined by myself. Can I use GridView or ListView accompanied with DataTemplate to display them and control the layout of  GridView by VisualStateManager?

Comment: I guess so. You can set the items of the GridView in xaml and if items are added\removed (visibility changes) the GrideView would update the ui to adjust it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

> In my UWP project, I want to split my window according to the number of elements to be displayed.

The best way to achieve this is creating your own custom Panel. Details about creating custom panel: [Custom Panel Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/custom-panels-overview).

I have created a simple custom panel, you can modify the codes to let it be adjusted to your detailed requirements:

```
public class AdaptivePanel:Panel
{
    private int rows;
    private int cols;

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int childrenCount = Children.Count;
        //calculate the row count /column count of the panel
        rows = (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt((double)childrenCount));
        cols = rows;
        double elementWidth,elementHeight = 0;
        elementWidth = availableSize.Width / cols;
        //for stackpanel height is infinity, take it into consideration
        if (!double.IsInfinity(availableSize.Height))
        {
            elementHeight = availableSize.Height / rows;
        }
        else
        {
            elementHeight = elementWidth;
        }

        foreach (FrameworkElement child in Children)
        {
            //mesure the children
            child.Measure(new Size(elementWidth, elementHeight));
        }

        return new Size(availableSize.Width,double.IsInfinity(availableSize.Height)?availableSize.Width:availableSize.Height);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {

        // Get total number of children
        int count = Children.Count;
        int index = 0;
        UIElement child=null;
        //arrange the elements in the panel
        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                if (index >= count)
                {
                    break;
                }
                child = Children[index];
                double boxLength = finalSize.Width / cols;
                //colNumber=j, rowNumber=i
                double x = finalSize.Width / cols * j;
                double y = finalSize.Height / rows * i;
                //if the element is bigger than the box then use the normal anchorPoint otherwise let it be in the middle of the box.
                double elementX=x, elementY=y;
                if (child.DesiredSize.Width < boxLength)
                {
                    elementX = x + (boxLength - child.DesiredSize.Width) / 2;
                }
                if (child.DesiredSize.Height < boxLength)
                {
                    elementY = y + (boxLength - child.DesiredSize.Height) / 2;
                }

                Point anchorPoint = new Point(elementX, elementY);
                Children[index].Arrange(new Rect(anchorPoint,child.DesiredSize));
                index++;
            }
        }


        return finalSize;
}
```

And usage:

```
<Page
...
xmlns:panels="using:AdaptivePanelSample.Panels"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<panels:AdaptivePanel x:Name="myPanel">
    <Rectangle Width="200" Height="200" Fill="Aqua"/>
    <Rectangle Width="200" Height="200" Fill="Aqua"/>
    <Rectangle Width="200" Height="200" Fill="Aqua"/>
</panels:AdaptivePanel>
</page>
```

And here is the complete demo:[AdaptivePanelSample](https://github.com/elvisxia/AdaptivePanelSample).